# SQL query to output multiple columns based on the value of 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, group-by, pivot

I have been banging my head against a wall at this now for a few hours. I have managed to get all the data I need down to 1 table, but I just can not figure out how to write a select statement so the output is the way I want.

Basically I have a table:

```
ID| Date | Cost
a  03/11   5
a  02/11   4
b  01/11   3
b  04/11   7
```

The column that changes the query column output is the date column. I would like to be able to group all the ID's together, with each row containing the ID and the cost of each item per month that pertains to that id, or null if there were no items that month (from jan-dec)

Output of query:

```
ID| JAN |FEB | MARCH | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL |......| OCT | NOV | DEC
a   NULL  4      5      NULL NULL.................................NULL
b   3    NULL   NULL     7   NULL.................................NULL
```

Any help in the right direction is appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: are your dates really stored as `03/11` (*string*)

Comment: Month(fieldnamehere)... that should point you in the right direction...

Comment: @ J W, no..this was just an example
@ MaxOvrdrv, I am able to determine what month a date falls under. I'm having trouble with using that information in the manner I have described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;with data(ID, Date, Cost) as (
    select 'a', '20110311', 5 union all
    select 'a', '20110211', 4 union all
    select 'b', '20110111', 3 union all
    select 'b', '20110411', 7
)
--- the above just creates a virtual dataset named data.
--- Your query starts below here

select *
  from
    (
    select ID, left(upper(datename(month,Date)),3) Month_, Cost
    from data
    ) p
 pivot (sum(Cost) for Month_ in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec])) v
```

Comment: Thank you so much Richard, exactly what I was looking for.

As a result, I have gone and done some reading on pivots. For anyone else who comes across a problem like this here is a good link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

again, thank you Richard!